# Auto complete json issue

Tags: asp.net, json

I have my webservice method like below:

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function TravelMeansList(ByVal prefix As String) As List(Of HRM_travellingMeans)
        Dim ctx As New HRMEntities
        Dim query = From c In ctx.HRM_travellingMeans Where c.name.ToUpper.StartsWith(prefix) Select c

        If query.Count > 0 Then
            Return query.ToList()
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

    End Function
```

and my script like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#<%=travelmeansTextBox.ClientID %>").autocomplete({


             source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../../services/ApplicationService.asmx/TravelMeansList") %>',
                     data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                     success: function (data) {
                         response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                             return Json({

                                    value: item.name
                             })
                         }))
                     },
                     error: function (response) {
                         alert(response.responseText);
                     },
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response.responseText);
                     }
                 });
             },
             select: function (e, i) {

             },
             minLength: 1
         });




     });
    </script>
```

My problem is that anytime i try to type any letter in my textbox i get this error

A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type \u0027System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationType\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable ......

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: @Shyju my class structure is:   Public id as Int32, Public name as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may lie with the JSON serialization of the Entity Framework object. Refer to this article:

http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/index.php/2010/02/serializing-entity-framework-objects-into-json-using-asp-net-mvc/

The author here suggests that you use a JSONResult object if you are using ASP.NET MVC, though I'm not sure how well that would play with jQuery Autocomplete.